# Dijkstra's algorithm with minimum edge

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra, breadth-first-search

So first let's define [Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) algorithm:
Dijkstra's algorithm finds single-source shortest paths in a directed graph with non-negative edge weights.
If I have a source S and destination T I can find a shortest path between this two vertices with **Dijkstra** algorithm but here is the problem I want to find the shortest path between this two vertices which the number of edges between this two does not exceed form K.
The first part is Dijkstra algorithm but second is kind of **BFS** algorithm because we can find the shortest path in none weighted graph with **BFS** algorithm.
So I am wondering is there a way that can some how change the **dijkstra** in order to solve this problem?
Any solution would be grateful.

Comment: What does "does not exceed from T" mean?

Comment: for example let's define k=4 we have path between S and T that contain 5 edge and the cost of this path is 10 and this is the shortest path but we another path with 3 edge but the cost is 11 I want to find this path with dijkstra algorithm

Comment: @ user2225104 Sorry I edit my question that second T was K that was my mistake I'am so sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Bellman-Ford's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm), and instead to run until `|V| - 1` in the outer loop, run until `k`. The outer loop iterator indicates the maximal length of the shortest path from the source to each target.

From wikipedia (with the outer loop index modification)

```
   for i from 1 to k: //here up to k instead to |V|
       for each edge (u, v) with weight w in edges:
           if distance[u] + w < distance[v]:
               distance[v] := distance[u] + w
               predecessor[v] := u
```

Comment: Was just about to post the same but was not sure it was correct :) +1

Comment: what a brilliant idea how can I missed it thank you so much :)

Comment: You should use a second array to update the distances and then copy them back to the distance array.